# string split into lines php by pattern

Tags: php, split

I have a string like this:

```
1. 192.168.122.1 0.89 Bps 2. 192.168.122.10 0.25 Bps
```

I want to split the string into two strings like this:

```
192.168.122.1 0.89 Bps
192.168.122.10 0.25 Bps
```

Comment: So What your research says? Where you got failed? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried explode ,split , str splits all the things still couldnt find the way thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) example:

```
$str = "1. 192.168.122.1 0.89 Bps 2. 192.168.122.10 0.25 Bps";

$split = preg_split("~\s?\d\.\s~", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => 192.168.122.1 0.89 Bps
    [1] => 192.168.122.10 0.25 Bps
)
*/
```

Comment: You may want to add `+` quantifier to your `\d` if they have more than 9 items.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a regular expression. `\d` is a shortcut to the `[0-9]` character class, which is used often in the following expression.

```
preg_match_all('/\d+\. \d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+ [\d.]+ Bps/', $str, $matches);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Vd6CIG).

In your example, `$matches` will contain...

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(25) "1. 192.168.122.1 0.89 Bps"
    [1]=>
    string(26) "2. 192.168.122.10 0.25 Bps"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the built-in preg_split() function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Comment: Is this an answer? more like comment

Answer (score 1):

Are they always guaranteed to be in that order? Is anything static, what changes, etc.?

Not really enough criteria here, but you'll probably be looking at exploding spaces and going from there...

```
<?php
$str = "1. 192.168.122.1 0.89 Bps 2. 192.168.122.10 0.25 Bps";
$arr = explode(" ", $str);
$your_result = "{$str[1]} {$str[3]} {$str[4]}\n{$str[6]} {$str[7]} {$str[8]}";
?>
```